# Unable to start PostgreSQL: Operation not Permitted

Tags: postgresql

I have a question about starting and using postgresql once it has been installed.
Here is the command that I have used and the error message:

```
dbacc@dbacc-Compaq-615:~$ /etc/init.d/postgresql start

chmod: changing permissions of `/var/run/postgresql': Operation not permitted
```

The installation seemed to go well. I must be missing something (Ubuntu rookie).

Thank you for any suggestions you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be superuser to run the software using the init.d script.

Try using `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start` to run the software.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, that worked! Although I am still having problems setting up the program. I have read the instructions about setting up and configuring the server and tried all of the commands, but nothing else works. Do you know of an online resource that might be better for a beginner than the Postgresql manual?? Thank you!

Comment: @David [Does this page from the community docs help? (click this)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL)  Also, don't forget to accept this as the answer if it helped.

Comment: Thanks again, Thomas. The info on the link looks just like what I need! How do I "accept" your answer??? Ok, now I see the button to "accept". Ubuntu members like you are an amazing help! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad I could help you out!  :)